# Wrong language of books when searching with ISBN on Google Books API

Tags: google-api, google-books

I'm using the Google Books JSON API to get information about books. But all responses I get back is in my local language, even if I query using an english title. Does anyone know if there's any parameter I can set to give results in a certain language? Or can I prevent Google from using my location to get the results in any way?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `langRestrict` parameter, in order to restrict results to books with the given language code.
Check out: https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#langRestrict

Hope that helps.

Comment: not working ... wait now it works guess the api needs a little time to adjust the request